# Prove normal and abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I was wondering if this is correct? Im insecure because the question says the lowest subgroup.

Comment: "Im insecure because the question says the lowest subgroup." If you're familiar with the concept of "subgroup generated by" there shouldn't be problems: $G'$ is the set of all possible products of elements $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, $x,y\in G$. Note $[x,y]=[y,x]^{-1}$; so inverses are already there.

Comment: Your proofs look good to me.

Comment: Oh okey how can i improve My proof on question a. Thank you for your help